# azure A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of

Tags: azure, security, networking, outbound

I already did the setup of My web app, made a Vnet Integration, My Virtual network is connected to my Default Subnet that is using My Security Group, in the security group I did the setup of outbound enabling

Source: Any
destination: 201.87.165.102
Service: 443
Allow

And I still receiving the message

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 201.87.165.102:443

Any tip?

Comment: This application works local, only doesn't work on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, you don't give enough data to diagnose your issue.

BTW, I assume you did the VNET integration to access some resources running in your VNET. But I don't see why you would need to update your security group in order to allow access to your public webapp. Your webapp should be accessible independently of your VNET.

You need to check a few things in order to find which part is wrong:

- Is the app working?
- Is it listening on HTTPS (tcp:443)?
- Is the public IP you use (201.87.165.102) the right one?
- ...

Comment: This application works local, only doesn't work on Azure.

Comment: As they said "It works on my machine!". It just means Azure and your laptop are different (for sure) but they are also configured differently: